# Android and PhpmyAdmin backend connection

Tags: android, arraylist, request, backend

I'm trying to send and receive data between my android application and server (phpmyadmin) 
i managed to send and receive data but only string and integers, now i'm trying to send from my android app an arraylist , and this arraylist i'm getting it from a class extends application.
and here's my code :

```
OrderManager om = (OrderManager) getApplication();
            ArrayList<OrderStrings> lstOrder = om.getLstOrder();

            Object[] mStringArray = lstOrder.toArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length; i++) {
                Log.d("string is", (String) mStringArray[i]);
                String request = "http://192.168.1.3/insertfinalorder.php?array=";
                request += mStringArray;
            }
```

when i print the request in the logcat, what i get inside the array is android.widget.... and not the data of the arraylist itself 
could u guys please help me :) 
Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line below should not be in the for loop. You should declare this above the for loop and then append the values of arraylist. Hope this helps you out.

```
String request = "http://192.168.1.3/insertfinalorder.php?array=";
```

Comment: i tried it .. but it didnt work too :( 
it gives a new respone in the logcat : 

04-12 14:59:22.130: D/response(12128): response:[Ljava.lang.Object;@4153c488

Answer (score 0):

Parse your list to XML or JSON first. These are languages meant for communication cases like this.

Comment: yes im using the JSON parsing ,, i just have the problem in attaching the array list in the request.. 
when i try to print the arraylist in the logcat it gives : 
04-12 14:59:22.130: D/response(12128): response:[Ljava.lang.Object;@4153c488

Comment: Because you're not parsing the arraylist to JSON. Now it just sends whatever value .toString() comes up with.